# Intellij closes automatically without errors

Tags: intellij-idea, windows-7, java-8

It looks like intellij decides to shutdown itself after some time. In some cases it takes about 10 minutes or even less, or it can take a couple of hours. It does not look like a memory problem, there is available heap memory.

An excerpt of the logs:

```
2016-08-09 09:32:33,390 [2312568]   INFO - tor.impl.FileEditorManagerImpl - Project opening took 2941 ms 
2016-08-09 09:32:57,553 [2336731]   INFO - odeInspection.bytecodeAnalysis - Too many equations for org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext run(java.lang.Object, java.lang.String...) 
2016-08-09 09:32:57,561 [2336739]   INFO - odeInspection.bytecodeAnalysis - Too many equations for org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext run(java.lang.Object, java.lang.String...) 
2016-08-09 09:41:53,378 [      0]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - ------------------------------------------------------ IDE STARTED ------------------------------------------------------ 
2016-08-09 09:41:53,424 [     46]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - IDE: IntelliJ IDEA (build #IU-145.972.3, 14 May 2016 00:00) 
2016-08-09 09:41:53,424 [     46]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - OS: Windows 7 (6.1, x86) 
2016-08-09 09:41:53,424 [     46]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - JRE: 1.8.0_77-b03 (Oracle Corporation) 
2016-08-09 09:41:53,424 [     46]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - JVM: 25.77-b03 (Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM) 
2016-08-09 09:41:53,427 [     49]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - JVM Args: -Xms256m -Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=250m -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=240m -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=50 -ea -Dsun.io.useCanonCaches=false -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow -Djb.vmOptionsFile=C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1\bin\idea.exe.vmoptions -Xbootclasspath/a:C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1\lib\boot.jar -Didea.paths.selector=IntelliJIdea2016.1 -Didea.jre.check=true
```

Before the IDE STARTED section, the IDE was closed automatically. The `Two many equations` does not seem to be correlated with this issue because in other cases the IDE closes without that being the last message.

Comment: Create a ticket with Jetbrains, they are very helpful and respond fast. https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/requests/new?ticket_form_id=66731

Comment: State your operating system and Java version.

Comment: @m0skit0 you can read it in log file ;) W7, 1.8

Comment: @Sarseth Those should be tags ;)